# Background из assets не правильный размер

Tags: android

Загружаю background элемента RelativeLayout из assets используя след. код:

```
        InputStream ims = getAssets().open(dbfile.getPath());

        BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        opts.inDensity = DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_TV;

        return Drawable.createFromResourceStream(getApplication().getResources(), null, ims, name, opts);
```

Результат заношу в setBackground(Drawable d).

Задник не растягиваеться по всей поверхности RelativeLayout, а покрывает только  часть. Как сделать покрытие  всей поверхности элемента?

Дополнение: Как я понимаю картинка не растягиваеться из за отсутствия авто-скэйла при загрузке из assets. По идее указание density в drawable уведомляет систему о исходном размере, если текущие параметры елементов отличаються, то система должна скэлить текстуру.... как я понял, но это не работает

layout код:

```
<com.app.ugooslauncher.elements.UgoosRelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:font="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/rlItemApps"
android:gravity="center"
android:focusable="true">

<com.app.ugooslauncher.views.TypefacedTextView
    android:id="@+id/apps_name"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:lines="2"
    android:textColor="#424141"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    font:typeface="OpenSans-Regular.ttf"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/apps_image"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/apps_name"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Рубленное решение без предоставления layout.xml топик стартером это просто вместо background вставить на задний фон ImageView со scaleType="fitXY"
например:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
 <ImageView
    android:id ="@+id/backgroun"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
            <!-- твой код -->
 </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: уверен т.к при выставлении с ресурсов бэкграунда все работает нормально, текстура полностью покрывает layout

Comment: Для уточнений вопроса используйте комментарии. Ответы только для решения проблемы в вопросе, а не обсуждений решения этой проблемы

Comment: можно увидеть layout.xml? (модератору: у меня не хватает очков чтобы оставлять комментарии под темой топик стартера. Что вообще очень странно, должно быть наоборот)

Comment: Да это решение-костыль, но должен же быть способ решить проблему нормально...

Comment: У меня нет в текущих проекта assets под боком поэтому мне сейчас сложно без лишних действий проверить. Проблема может скрываться либо в том чтобы поиграть с логикой создания Drawable через Bitmap как в createFromResourceStream. либо в том чтобы сначала удостоверится что Layout отрисовался в нужном размере а уже потом вставлять Drawable. Без возможности проверить это просто догадки. Попробуйте задать фиксированный размер RelativeLayout в dp - это даст отсеять второе предположение, так как меня cмущает wrap_content в вашем RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 0):

В BitmapOptions    .outHeight и .outWeight должны быть равны тому RelativeLayout на который drawable ставится, получить актуальный размер этого лэйаута можно через ViewTreeObderver.